# Secure Erase NVMe Drive with nvme cli //CMD_SEQ_ERROR:

Tags: hard-drive, security, nvme, secure-erase

Trying to Secure Erase NVM drive but failed with CMD_SEQ_ERROR:
Below is a summary of what/how I am doing to perform the Secure Erase.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think for Crypto Erase you are supposed to run it with the `--ses=2` option.  See https://www.ibm.com/docs/el/linux-on-systems?topic=devices-secure-data-deletion-nvme-drive

Comment: Hi,
Have checked with --ses=2 and it shows the same error message as was with --ses=1.

Comment: I hate to ask this, but have you tried this secure erase from a Live boot to eliminate the running OS from locking the drive through a mount?

Comment: I have booted the machine with a USB stick.

Comment: You might want to see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310338/how-to-secure-erase-a-nvme-ssd  Beyond this, I am out.  I don't have an NVME drive so I am not much help from here.  Good luck and I hope you can find a solution.

Comment: Have checked this already, not useful at least for my case. Thanks anyways.